# How can I restart IIS from C# code running as a user who is an administrator?

Tags: c#, .net, iis, windows-7, admin

Typically (in Windows 7), installing a program will ask for permission to modify the system.  As an administrator, I can give the authorization without supplying a password.

I'm trying to figure out how to take an administrator action (restart IIS) from C# code running as a user who is AN administrator, but the not THE "Administrator" account.

Answer (score 5):

To run a process as elevated you can use the *runas* verb.

```
Process elevated = new Process();
elevated.StartInfo.Verb = "runas";
elevated.StartInfo.FileName = "Whatever.exe";
elevated.Start();
```

For restarting IIS (as mentioned before) use iisreset.

Hope you find this useful.

Comment: In a command prompt, when I type "runas /user:Administrator iisreset", it asks me for a password, even though the user who launched the command prompt is an administrator.  I should not need a password.

Comment: I don't think that the runas command is exactly the same as the runas verb. From the question I assumed that You would like to do this from code.

Answer (score 4):

For anyone still looking for this, here is code that I use to help me out with this.

```
    private static void DoIISReset()
    {
        Process iisReset = new Process();
        iisReset.StartInfo.FileName = "iisreset.exe";
        iisReset.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        iisReset.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        iisReset.Start();
        iisReset.WaitForExit();
    }
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I using full path for filename : `(@"C:\Windows\System32\iisreset.exe")`

Comment: How to do it but for remote iis?

Answer (score 3):

Try to execute the `IISReset` command from C#

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc758159(WS.10).aspx

```
iisreset /noforce
```

Using `ProcessStart`

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"C:\Windows\System32\iisreset.exe");
```

If you're using AD Authentication and you're an administrator this should work

Comment: I'm not using AD authentication, I'm just on a home computer.  And it didn't work.

Comment: issreset.exe -> iisreset.exe

Answer (score 3):

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"C:\Windows\System32\iisreset.exe");
```

This code help to you but you can get Access Denied.

For you  to not get Access Denied:

1. Right Click Project
2. Add New İtem
3. [Add Application Manifest File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FxkHl.png)
4. Change this section

`<requestedExecutionLevel level="asInvoker" uiAccess="false" />`

To this

`<requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />`

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to do this but fr both you need to run VS as administration.

1. This code will prompt in an empty **cmd** for some time and will close the window automatically.

   `Process iisReset = new Process();
    iisReset.StartInfo.FileName = "iisreset.exe";
    iisReset.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    iisReset.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    iisReset.Start();
    iisReset.WaitForExit();`

   2. this code will also restart IIS and it will prompt **CMD** with few processing.

      `Process.Start(@"C:\WINDOWS\system32\iisreset.exe", "/noforce");`

Answer (score -1):

Here is a link to how this is done in power shell
http://www.computerperformance.co.uk/powershell/powershell_service_start.htm

Another possibility would be to use WMI 
http://www.motobit.com/tips/detpg_vbs-wmi-restart-service/

Here is another way directly in #
http://www.csharp-examples.net/restart-windows-service/

I hope this helps....

Comment: This does not answer the question around the requirement of doing it in C#

Comment: @Dave Friedel, The last link has C# examples how to restart a service. So it does answer the question

Comment: I'll remove the down vote, but you do not provide the specifics for restarting IIS with a link to a remote site that doesn't answer the question.  To provide value, some pseudo code outlining the action would be more useful to the community. - Update - my vote is locked unless the answer is edited. Plus it would lead them down other issues like the link here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19763527/why-my-c-sharp-does-not-have-system-serviceprocess-library