# Restarting IIS programmatically

Tags: c#, .net, iis, process, uac

I need to restart IIS from a C#/.NET application. This seems like a trivial issue, but I haven't had success thus far, and none of the answers from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7870745/how-can-i-restart-iis-from-c-sharp-code-running-as-a-user-who-is-an-administrato) have worked.

I am a local administrator on the machine.

I've tried this:

```
var process = new Process
{
   StartInfo =
   {
       Verb = "runas",
       WorkingDirectory = @"C:\Windows\System32\",
       FileName = @"issreset.exe"
   }
};
process.Start();
```

but this throws a `Win32Exception - cannot find the file specified.` I've also tried various combinations of putting the whole path in `FileName`, and using `UseShellExecute` but neither of those options helped.

I've also tried invoking it via the command line:

```
var process = new Process
{
   StartInfo =
   {
       Verb = "runas",
       WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden,
       FileName = @"cmd.exe",
       Arguments = "/C iisreset"
   }
};
process.Start();
```

and this works, but it gives a UAC prompt, which I cannot have as this application will be running without user intervention.

Is there anything else I could try?

Comment: I think you want `iisreset.exe`, not `iisreset`.  You need the file name extension.

Comment: You're right. That was a typo on my part in writing the question. I have tried that.

Comment: The first will work if you set `UseShellExecute` to true.  Otherwise, `FileName` has to be the full path.  There is no way to bypass the UAC, which is kinda the point.  You could turn it off on that machine.

Comment: Your first snippet of code works fine for me.  Are you sure that's the code you've tried?  Are you sure IIS is installed and the file is there?

Comment: This doesnt bypass UAC, but it only prompts for a password: `runas /user:Administrator iisreset` as an argument to your second process.

Comment: You've got `"issreset.exe"`, it should be `"iisreset.exe"`. (iss != iis)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception you're getting is most likely caused by the fact that the user you are trying to run this application as does not have administrative privileges.

If you run your application as an administrator account then it should automatically launch iisreset with administrative privileges without a UAC prompt or an error.

How you should go about running your process as an administrator is a separate issue.  The most common way is to create an application manifest:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235229.aspx

Comment: The privileges did end up being the issue here. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Right click on project name in Solution Explorer ->Add ->New Item-> Appliaction Manifest File.

In it edit the

```
    <requestedPrivileges>
       <requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
    </requestedPrivileges>
```

this should solve your issue.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively (and cleaner) you could just use the `ServiceController` class to subsequently stop and start the iis service.
You'll probably still need elevated privileges though... Impersonation might solve this;  "[impersonate an account with higher privileges.](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10090/A-small-C-Class-for-impersonating-a-User)" for restarting the service.

A good example of how to start/stop (and restart) a windows service can be found here: 
[Start, Stop and Restart Windows Service (C#)](http://www.csharp-examples.net/restart-windows-service/)

Comment: What would the name of the IIS service be? I don't see it in Task Manager -> Services tab in Windows 8.

Comment: I found out it is "w3svc" from this blog post http://mphokazito.wordpress.com/2011/02/07/how-to-restart-iis-using-c/

Answer (score 2):

FileName is wrong. try `FileName = @"iisreset.exe"`

Answer (score 0):

Another option to start the IIS:

```
string serviceName = "W3SVC"; //W3SVC refers to IIS service
ServiceController service = new ServiceController(serviceName);
service.Start();
service.WaitForStatus(ServiceControllerStatus.Running);// Wait till the service started and is running
```